# Как настроить права в Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Решил разобраться в Docker и сделать себе сборку для laravel (LEMP).

Структура сборки:

- docker - файлы настроек и Dockerfile для mysql,php,nginx
- hosts - настройки вир.хостов (nginx)
- logs - логи nginx
- mysql - файлы БД
- www ‒ директории проектов

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда логи nginx, которые попадают в директорию ./logs - создаются под root. Соответственно, если требуется их удалить - необходимо лезть в консоль для: `sudo rm *.log`

Содержание: docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3'
services:
  #Php-fpm Service
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php/
      dockerfile: php-fpm.docker
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx/
      dockerfile: nginx.docker
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./hosts/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - app
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #MariaDB Service
  db:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: mariadb.docker
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #PHPMyadmin Service
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: pma
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 81:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network


#Docker Networks
networks:
  laravel-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Изначально была аналогичная проблема с MariaDB - все файлы создавались под root, пофиксить - запустив контейнер не от root пользователя.

Dockerfile для mariadb:

```yml
FROM mariadb:latest

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
USER www
```

Такой же прием попробовал применить для контейнера Nginx, но возникла проблема.

Содержание Dockerfile для nginx:

```yml
FROM nginx

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

USER www
```

В таком виде - nginx не стартует с ошибками:

```bsh
webserver    | 2020/10/28 07:09:25 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
webserver    | nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
webserver    | 2020/10/28 07:09:25 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
webserver    | nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Если попробовать выдать 777 на /var/cache/nginx/ (`RUN chmod -R 777 /var/cache/nginx/`), то появляется другая ошибка:

```bsh
webserver    | 2020/10/28 07:12:54 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
webserver    | nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
webserver    | 2020/10/28 07:12:54 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
webserver    | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Могу предположить - проблема связана с правами, но я не могу разобраться, как заставить nginx стартовать от имени созданного пользователя (www).

Не подскажите, как пофиксить данную проблему или может посоветуете вариант получше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, может будет кому пригодится... Проблема заключалась: **Если запускать контейнер (nignx) с понижением прав (не root). Нельзя использовать порты ниже 1000**, а также с хоста в контейнер нужно пробросить модифицированный nginx.conf.

модифицированный nginx.conf

```
# worker_processes по количеству ядер процессора
worker_processes  6;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_body_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  #Php-fpm Service
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./logssss:/var/log/
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:4430'
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./hosts/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - app
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #MariaDB Service
  db:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - laravel-network

  #PHPMyadmin Service
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: pma
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 81:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - laravel-network


#Docker Networks
networks:
  laravel-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile(Nginx)

```
FROM nginx

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
USER www
```

После этого и nginx завелся и логи из контейнера в хосте создаются не под root